# How to join attributes by field value on-the-fly?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, attribute-joins

I have two spatial (polygon) layers (table 1 and 2), and another non spatial table (table 3).

Table 1 & Table 2 have identical columns but different fields.
Table 1 is edited by user 1 only
Table 2 is edited by user 2 only

The work is allocated through table 3. Table 1 and Table 2 are joined to Table 3, and work allocation to user 1 and user 2 could be altered by changing table 3.

Columns of Table 1 & 2
1 - Job done
2 - Parcel ID
3 - User

Table 3
1 - Parcel ID
2 - User

In MapInfo I used to create a view of the Table 1 and Table 2 with table 3 by SQL select. If I needed to transfer work from Table 1 to Table 2 I could just change the user in column 2 of Table 3.

Is there a way to do this in QGIS i.e. is it possible to do Join Attributes by Field Value on-the-fly? I tried to create a virtual layer, but virtual layers are not editable.

Comment: There is a *Joins* tab in *Layer Properties* (Right-click layer name -> Properties), perhaps that will suit your needs.

Comment: Can you please show your efforts with Virtual Layers, actually they are editable?

Comment: @Matt I had a similar problem, tried your solution and it worked. Thanks